# /usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory when running vscode task

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, gulp, visual-studio-code

I have a basic task setup to build my TypeScript and Sass files. It looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Gulp Build",
      "group": "build",
      "command": "./node_modules/.bin/gulp",
      "type": "shell",
      "args": [
        "build"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ]
}
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+B</kbd> to select a build task, I select the one above and in my terminal I get this:

> > Executing task: ./node_modules/.bin/gulp build <
>
> /usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
>   The terminal process terminated with exit code: 127

I have exported the variables:

**.gnomerc** and **.bashrc**:

```
export PATH="$NVM_BIN:$NPM_HOME:$PATH"
```

**Note:** Both `Node` and `NPM` were both installed using `NVM`

If I open the editor from my **Favorites** or through **Activities**, I get the above error. If I open from the command line, it works fine. How can I get this working without having to open from the command line every time?

Comment: Hi @get-off-my-lawn, please do accept the answer if it worked for you, or leave a comment if it didn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

This happens because `.bashrc` is not loaded for tasks, as they are non-interactive shells. You need to have the nvm shell enhancements loaded for non-interactive shells as well to use global packages installed via nvm to be available to VS Code.

Create a new text file named, say, `nvm-autoload.sh` and place it inside `/etc/profile.d/` folder to run it for all login shells, which includes the task shells for VS Code. Add the following to that file:

```
# Enable nvm if available
if [ -f ~/.nvm/nvm.sh ]; then
  source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
fi
```

You may need to logout and log back in for this to take effect.

Comment: Thank you!  Works perfect.  But for mac it is /etc/profile

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04, vscode 1.61.0

Comment: worked like a charm, used this on my ansible playbook https://github.com/ed3899/vagrant-base-ubuntu-jammy